# TeXMaker keybindings: accept code suggestion with `TAB`, but not `ENTER`?

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion, keyboard

I have looked around and did not see a question about this.

TeXMaker has a feature where it gives code suggestions. For example when you type \fra, it suggests

```
\frac{•}{•}
```

I use this feature with the `TAB` key. However "accept suggestion" is mapped to both `TAB` and `ENTER`. Is there some way to remove the `ENTER` map so that only `TAB` accepts a code suggestion? The `ENTER` hotkey gets in the way of usual typing and I don't use it anyway.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem. I use Texmaker and tab + enter doesn't change anything!

Comment: What I mean is that when TeXMaker gives a suggestion (for example, autocompleting \fra into \frac{}{}) you cannot use "Enter" to make a new line, since it is now mapped to autocomplete. I would like to disable this hotkey since I use tab for autocomplete anyway.

Comment: I didn't understand which hotkey do you want to disable?

Comment: Suppose you wrote \fra in TeXMaker. Then underneath, a suggestion pops up saying frac{•}{•}. If you then press Enter or Tab, TeXMaker replaces your "\fra" with "\frac{•}{•}". I am looking for a way to disable the "Enter" hotkey for this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like the enter key to have no effect on the completion and instead the TAB key to be the only active key, is that right?

Comment: That's exactly right, I edited the question to make it more clear, thanks for the help

Comment: The completion uses scripts written in javascript (qtscript) exactly. [4.15 Extending the editor's functionality with scripts](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION45). Not knowing javascript, I am of no help, sorry. In revenge, you can write directly to Pascal Brachet `pbrachet@xm1math.net`  the Texmaker maintainer to ask him if this is possible or not. He is French but I think he is fluent in English.